# How to ensure accounts aren't bots (Algorand)?

Tags: smartcontracts, algorand, pyteal

not sure if this question belongs here... We are doing a giveaway but we have >30K wallets signed up. We're worried that many are bots. Have you encountered this yet? AND/OR does anyone have a solution to check each wallet transaction history to see if they have any transactions across other signed up wallets? We checked Algo Explorer and it seems that most cases there's a parent wallet and they're sending from the main wallet to a bunch of sub-wallets... thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no good way to prevent this unless you had some form of KYC. I could have a bot create fresh wallets with no transaction history that would be impossible to correlate with each other. Then if those wallets got an asset from you I could then just have them send that asset to the "main" wallet.

You could also set a minimum value of ALGO required to hold in the wallet to be eligible. It wouldn't completely solve the problem, but would make it more expensive for the people operating the bots at least.

Alternatively, set up a centralized service with email + captcha, make each address owner validate their address via that service and deny if they don't.